# Array Scope for window.requestFileSystem in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

the following code gives me a conflicting answer.
The Array is global but no in scope the function? I don't understand.
Here's the code

```
  var pictures = new Array();

  var app = {
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);       
  },
  onDeviceReady: function() {

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
        function(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory("DCIM/Camera/", {create: false},
                function(dataDir) {
                   var directoryReader = dataDir.createReader();
                   directoryReader.readEntries(
                       function(entries){
                           var i;                           
                           for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                               pictures[i] = entries[i].fullPath;                                   
                            }
                            console.log(pictures.length + ' ---- in');
                        }, fail)
                }, fail);
        }, fail);  

    console.log(pictures.length + ' ---- out');
```

...
When pictures into the function, webconsole value=176

When pictures out the function, webconsole value=0

Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe `requestFileSystem` is asynchronous. I would guess you first see the `out` console logging and then the `in` console logging because of this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the FileSystem API calls are asynchronous.

For example if you run the code:

```
var i = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
  i = 10;
  console.log('i in: ' + i);
}, 100);

console.log('i out: ' + i);
```

You will see that I behaves similar to what you're seeing due to the fact that the setTimeout occurs after "the console.log('i out: ' + i);". The same concept applies to the FileSystem calls you're using.